# Debounce does not work in IE9

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-9, debouncing

My website currently uses a debounce directive with AngularJS v1.2.8. The debounce is fine in FF and Chrome but the delay does not happen in IE9. I have a strict requirement to support IE9 and I cannot upgrade to a newer version of Angular. What part of this code is not IE9 compatible? Or if there is a debounce directive that is already known to work in IE9 that would be greatly appreciated.

**Current debounce directive :**

```
angular.module('stuff.debounce', []).directive('ngDebounce', function($timeout) {


    return {
        restrive: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        priority: 99,
        link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            if(attr.type === 'radio' || attr.type === 'checkbox') return;

            elm.unbind('input');

            var debounce;

            elm.bind('input', function() {
               $timeout.cancel(debounce);
               debounce = $timeout( function () {
                  scope.$apply(function() {
                      ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(elm.val());
                  }); 
               }, attr.ngDebounce || 1000);
            });
            elm.bind('blur', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(elm.val());
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Well, just behind this script in github it's said that there is no compatibility with IE9. You better find an other one !

Comment: @Apédémak 1.2.8 supports IE8 and above. https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.8/docs/guide/ie

Comment: @KevinB I wasn't talking about Angular.... I was talking about this script find on github.

Comment: You might want to clarify your question then, it says verbatim: "I'm using angular js 1.2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried some other debounce apis but none of them worked so I wrote a little javascript method that works in IE9 for debouncing.

```
var deb = undefined;
$scope.someMethod = function() {
    if(deb !== undefined)
         $timeout.cancel(deb);
    deb = $timeout( function() {
         //do stuff that you want debounced
        deb = undefined;
    }, 1500); //1500 is the debounce delay in ms
};
```

Sorry if this is messy I had to write it from my phone.